# Invalid read size in strcasestr

Tags: c, valgrind

The following code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *s = strdup("keep-alive");
    if(strcasestr(s, "close")) {
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

gives the following error in Valgrind:

```
==13183== Invalid read of size 8
==13183==    at 0x4F53F94: __strcasestr_sse42 (emmintrin.h:685)
==13183==    by 0x4005BF: main (in /home/aaron/dev/strtest)
==13183==  Address 0x51ce048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 11 alloc'd
==13183==    at 0x4C28F9F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==13183==    by 0x4EB1441: strdup (strdup.c:43)
==13183==    by 0x4005A5: main (in /home/aaron/dev/strtest)
```

Has anyone else seen this?  This happens with & without optimizations, using gcc 4.6.1.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. By the way, you forgot a macro that enables those extensions, e.g. `#define _GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: what is the version of valgrind, can you retry with the last version of valgrind?

Comment: @KerrekSB Using GCC 4.6.1 you cannot reproduce this?  I have tried on earlier versions (4.5, 4.2, 4.1) & it's not an issue. As for its use in the real world where I first discovered the problem, I'm using g++ which defines _GNU_SOURCE - this is merely a bare snippet to reproduce that will compile.

Comment: I can reproduce this with gcc 4.6.1 and Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian

Comment: Nope, I cannot; both with gcc and with g++, 4.6.2, and valgrind 3.6.0. It just works fine.

Comment: @KerrekSB What kind of CPU do you have? a Core 2 or lower you wouldn't see this.

Comment: @nevelis: I think I I have a Core Duo. How weird that this should depend on the CPU...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only happening in valgrind, it's not an error. It would be undefined behavior for *your code* to read beyond the end of an object obtained by `malloc`, but `strcasestr` is part of "the implementation" and thus can use implementation-specific knowledge: in this case, the fact that over-reading is perfectly safe as long as you don't cross a page boundary.

Comment: It seems to be okay with values in multiples of 16. After looking in emmintrin.h:685 at "return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_loaddqu ((char const *)__P)", it looks like they're loading 16 bytes at a time. I'll assume the C lib knows what it's doing :D thanks for the insight.